# Какая версия написания кода более правильная

Tags: python, selenium

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
 button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('........').click()
 button.click()
```

И вот такой:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('......').click()
```

Оба рабочие. Какой более правильный... верный.

Comment: В этой строке:  `button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('........').click()` в `button` запишется, то что вернет метод `click()`. Если он не вернет ничего, то в `button` запишется `None`, и на следующей строке у вас будет ошибка, что у `NoneType` нет метода `click()`.

Comment: На самом деле оба варианта не правильны. Вы не обрабатываете возможность того, что элемент будет не виден на странице и клик по невидимому элементу выкинет ошибку

Comment: @insolor А у того, что возвращает метод ``click()``, есть метод ``click()``?

Comment: @Эникейщик если бы я работал с selenium, я бы ответил точно. Но скорее всего нет.

Comment: @insolor И мне тоже так кажется.

Comment: В ``button`` сохраняется результат метода click(), на который потом опять применяется метод click(). Это очень странная конструкция. Думаю, что если убрать из него второую строчку, то ничего не изменится. После этого можно убрать присвоение значения переменной ``button``, потому что она не будет использоваться. Т.о. получаем второй вариант -> он более правильный.

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо. Я тоже так писал всегда, но в инете практикуется первый вариант, вот и сомнения взяли

Comment: @danilshik Если оба варианта неверны, то, по вашему мнению, как надо?